# How to join json list with a table in SQL Server using OPENJSON?

Tags: sql-server, json

I have json data which have a list of productDetails. I need to combine each of the detail with productId.

I am using a stored procedure. This is my code:

```
DECLARE @products AS TABLE(productName NVARCHAR(255), 
                           productId INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @products  
    EXEC [saveproducts] @product;
```

From the above query, I will get the list of products as a table. Now I need to join the detail in the json with corresponding product

```
INSERT INTO @detail 
     SELECT
         [detaiId], [productId]
     FROM 
         OPENJSON(@detailJSON) 
     WITH(detailId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 'strict $.detaiId',
       productId INT ??????);
```

How to get the `productId` by comparing the `productName` in `@detailJSON` and from table `@products`?

Comment: Can you provide JSON sample (structure) and productDetails schema

Comment: @Habeeb.. I have solved it actually only a simle inner join is needed. Thanks for the edit and responce

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only a simple inner join is needed

```
 INSERT INTO @detail 
 SELECT
     J.[detaiId], P.[productId]
 FROM 
 @products P
 INNER JOIN
     OPENJSON(@detailJSON) 
 WITH(detailId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 'strict $.detaiId',
      productName  NVARCHAR(255) 'strict $.productName'
   ) J 
 ON J.productName = P.productName
```